# unable to connect to mongoDB getting error

Tags: php, mongodb

Hi I am trying to install mongo database on Ubuntu and after install when I run the command mongo getting this error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.14
connecting to: test
Sun Oct 11 12:06:28.161 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 0):

you may have with mongo lock i think this may fix your problem

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo service mongodb restart
```

Comment: fixed this issue getting another error The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled